# AMP project directs here for questions so I can't understand what the error is instructing me to do

Tags: amp-html

Google Webmaster Tools is showing me AMP errors but I don't see what it's asking. My AMP page and my URL page are listed and it tells me I have an error...but doesn't directly instruct me where the error is. Attached is the exact page I'm referring to.

[image: Screenshot]

There are 2 links so there's nothing to try really because it's just 2 links. They are live links, crawled, no crawl errors and the instructions don't say to correct the AMP page or the page the AMP page is being generated from. It just says there's an HTML error. Why wouldn't the other 300 AMP pages have this error when there's nothing different that I did with them.

Error in required structured data element. Disallowed attribute or attribute value present in HTML tag. Screenshot of the exact error.

Finding the error and understanding what AMP/GWT is instructing me to do.

Comment: Based from this [documentation](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/troubleshooting/validation_errors#disallowed-attribute), since attributes are whitelisted, there is no definitive list of all disallowed attributes. Check if the attributes you are using is supported for each specific tag. Search for HTML tag, and then `attrs` in the [AMP validator spec](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/validator/validator-main.protoascii).